# How to define IInterface type for Delphi 4

Tags: delphi, delphi-4

It seems that Delphi 4 does not have IInterface type at all in system.pas

How can I define this type myself so that I can use JEDI?

Comment: try type IInterface = IUnknown;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IInterface` was introduced later than Delphi 4. For Delphi 4 you use `IUnknown` in place of `IInterface`.

If memory serves, `IInterface` was introduced in Delphi 6 which was the release corresponding to the Kylix Linux compiler. The change was made to avoid exposing Windows specific `IUnknown` nomenclature to the new cross-platform Delphi.